# now that there is ARC is there a need to use retain

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I believe ARC will take care of all memory management issues, is there a reason to use retain. Is there a reason to use assign now ?

I tried to looked through some documentation, but could not find anything

if we dont need this stuff anymore, then what should we assign our properties when we create them? should we make everything strong ?

Comment: Is your question about retain/assign in *properties*?

Comment: no, based on what i know.. I think ARC might replace all this stuff.. i hope so.. I will wait to see how people here respond

Comment: If you're using ARC, I think the compiler refuses to allow you to use retain.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What do you mean by *"Is there a reason to use assign now?"*. - Perhaps you could give a concrete example what you are talking about.

Comment: i actually dont know about assign... but i am hoping that i dont have to learn this stuff.

Comment: @mah: No, it still allows you to use retain. It just means the same as `strong`. Of course, it's not recommended, but auto-generated `NSManagedObject` subclasses still use retain and that works fine.

Comment: ARC doesn't replace release/retain, it requires that you omit them so that the static analyzer / compiler ARC system can insert them in the correct places.

Comment: ARC handles most of the mundane memory management issues for you, but you definitely should still **learn this stuff**

Comment: ARC simplifies memory management for you but still you have to do some work to make it more efficient. By qualifying attributes with weak, strong and assign, you are making it easier for ARC to decide what to do with following properties. It is your responsibility to decide which properties should be attributed with which qualifiers to avoid retain cycles.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ARC you should make your properties either `weak` or `strong`.  You should use `weak` if you want the property to exist as long as some other object points to it and you should use `strong` if you want the property to exist as long as you (self) point to it.

For example, when your object has a pointer to a UIView in a storyboard or a xib (created by control-clicking and dragging to your interface), it will be a weak pointer, because you expect the UIView to only exist as long as the storyboard or xib allows it to exist.  To be more clear, the storyboard or xib owns that object.

While using ARC `retain` is the same as `strong`

Comment: this is really abstract, can you give a real example to further explain ?

Comment: `assign` is for use with primitive C data types.  `weak`/`retain`/`strong` are for objects.

Comment: additionally there is _strong qualifier to use it in certain cases

Answer (score 0):

Well since it is not allowing me to upvote the answer above me.  I will just respond with the same.  Since you have to use arc now when you set your properties list that weak and strong label are what replace the retain feature.  I typically will set everything to be strong in a single view application and then when I am using multi-view or a tabled application I am using weak.

Comment: ok that is interesting.. so why do you do that ? i mean, when you go multiview or tabled, why do you have to switch to weak ?

Comment: because weak is used for objects that are more temporary.  So due to the tabled view or multi-view we can say that there will be more temporary pointers due to use by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in many cases you want to override the default ARC behavior.

```
Eg: 

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *response;

-(void)parseHTTRResponse {

//responseString is an autoreleased object but assignment will increase retain count by 1
self.response =[self stringFromData:response.data];

// equivalent to first statement
__strong NSString *responseString = [self stringFromData:response.data];

}
```

Now the question is why would someone do this?

To increase autorelease life span for local variables which takes long time (generally object of NSURLConnection)